# several functions ajax json jquery/php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

http://emafia.co.uk/map/ : Use the top link on right to see what I have so far.

Can someone help me with the following please?

- a fix for only 1 text box to be selected at once
- submit function updates values in a mysql database and returns the results *(I've been told to use JSON for this, but every JSON function I've tried I cant get it to post the data and receive it)*

My HTML so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>land</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="map.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.credits{font-size: 1.6em; line-height: 2em; margin: 0 0 0 10px;}
</style>
</head>
```

Here's the HTML Body:

```
<body>
<p class="credits">&nbsp;</p>

<form action="" method="get">
    <div id="map-box">
        <div id="container-map">
            <img src="images/map.gif" alt="Map" name="map1" border="0" usemap="#map1Map" id="map" />
            <map name="map1Map" id="map1Map">
                <area class="sw" shape="poly" coords="162,319,162,303,186,303,186,264,162,264,162,287,175,282,160,297,140,298,110,335,138,335" alt="sw" />
                <area class="s" shape="poly" coords="186,264,206,264,206,312,179,313,162,318,162,303,186,303" alt="s" />
                <area class="se" shape="poly" coords="206,312,243,311,268,298,268,287,251,283,255,279,206,279" alt="se" />
                <area class="e" shape="poly" coords="206,279,255,279,270,267,276,241,252,230,246,238,237,233,221,233,221,264,206,264" alt="e" />
                <area class="em" shape="poly" coords="221,264,196,264,196,209,214,209,214,233,221,233" alt="em" />
                <area class="wm" shape="poly" coords="162,264,196,264,196,209,162,209" alt="wm" />
                <area class="w" shape="poly" coords="162,209,122,209,130,240,141,236,143,251,119,267,123,281,144,279,154,288,162,288" alt="w" />
                <area class="yl" shape="poly" coords="214,233,238,233,245,225,225,173,212,167,176,167,176,185,186,185,186,208" alt="yl" />
                <area class="nw" shape="poly" coords="186,209,169,209,174,184,163,187,156,169,163,155,160,153,176,137,176,185,186,185" alt="nw" />
                <area class="ne" shape="poly" coords="177,167,213,167,209,165,201,128,192,122,176,137" alt="ne" />
                <area class="scot" shape="poly" coords="160,153,192,122,177,110,163,114,170,104,179,100,172,93,178,92,198,49,193,42,162,42,141,51,148,32,166,14,169,1,144,7,125,2,114,34,86,47,86,55,106,69,106,79,95,83,95,98,109,97,113,108,106,138,111,138,116,113,132,131,121,153,124,161,131,159,137,166" alt="scot" />
                <area class="ni" shape="poly" coords="117,176,97,192,91,193,83,190,79,179,70,182,71,187,64,190,53,182,58,163,71,154,80,147,91,143,99,143" alt="ni" />
            </map>
        </div> <!--#container-map-->

        <div id="areas">
            <ul id="regions">
                <li class="nw">North West England <span class="nw-n"></span></li>
                <li class="ne">North East England <span class="ne-n"></span></li>
                <li class="yl">Yorkshire &amp; Lincolnshire <span class="yl-n"></span></li>
                <li class="wm">West Midlands <span class="wm-n"></span></li>
                <li class="em">East Midlands <span class="em-n"></span></li>
                <li class="sw">West &amp; South West <span class="sw-n"></span></li>
                <li class="e">East <span class="e-n"></span></li>
                <li class="s">South <span class="s-n"></span></li>
                <li class="se">London &amp; South East <span class="se-n"></span></li>
                <li class="scot">Scotland <span class="scot-n"></span></li>
                <li class="ni">Northern Ireland <span class="ni-n"></span></li>
                <li class="w">Wales <span class="w-n"></span></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="counties">

                <!--start-->
                <div id="st-c" class="counties-container">
                    <p class="tip">This is where you can wage war over territory, fight for the territory by blowing up drug factorys, destorying bullet rings and even try to do a hit on the owner to completly take over the land... more info shortly</p>
                    <p class="tip">Tip: Double clicking a region will select all counties in that region. (if there is multiple countrys in the region)</p>
                </div>

                <!--nw-->
                <div id="nw" class="counties-container">
                    <h2>North West</h2>

                    <p class="select"><a class="selectall" title="Select All">Select All</a> | <a class="deselectall" title="Deselect All">Deselect All</a></p>
                    <fieldset class="nw-t">

<p><b>Results:</b> <span id="results"></span></p>

  <form>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Manchester" id="ch1"/>

    <label for="ch1">Manchester</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value=" And Man city" id="ch2"/>

    <label for="ch1">Man city </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>


    <label for="r1">Bomb Factory's</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value=": Bomb" id="r1"/>

    <label for="r1">Attack Guards</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value=": Attack" id="r2"/>

    <label for="r1">Leave</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value=": Leave" id="r3"/>
  </form>

  <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit"/>


                    </fieldset>
                </div>


                <!--ne-->
                <div id="ne" class="counties-container">
                    <h2>North East</h2>
                    <p class="select"><a class="selectall" title="Select All">Select All</a> | <a class="deselectall" title="Deselect All">Deselect All</a></p>
                    <fieldset class="ne-t">                      
                        <input type="checkbox" /><label>Northumberland</label>                    
                    </fieldset>           
                </div>

                <!--yl-->
                <div id="yl" class="counties-container">
                    <h2>Yorkshire &amp; Lincolnshire</h2>
        <p class="select"><a class="selectall" title="Select All">Select All</a> | <a class="deselectall" title="Deselect All">Deselect All</a></p>
                    <fieldset class="yl-t">
                        <input type="checkbox" /><label>Yorkshire</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <!--wm-->
                <div id="wm" class="counties-container">
                    <h2>West Midlands</h2>
        <p class="select"><a class="selectall" title="Select All">Select All</a> | <a class="deselectall" title="Deselect All">Deselect All</a></p>
                    <fieldset class="wm-t">
                        <input type="checkbox" /><label>Staffordshire</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <!--em-->
                <div id="em" class="counties-container">
                    <h2>East Midlands</h2>
        <p class="select"><a class="selectall" title="Select All">Select All</a> | <a class="deselectall" title="Deselect All">Deselect All</a></p>
                    <fieldset class="em-t">
                        <input type="checkbox" /><label>Derbyshire</label>
                    </fieldset>

                </div>

                <!--sw-->
                <div id="sw" class="counties-container">
                    <h2>South West</h2>
                    <p class="select"><a class="selectall" title="Select All">Select All</a> | <a class="deselectall" title="Deselect All">Deselect All</a></p>
                    <fieldset class="sw-t">
                        <input type="checkbox" /><label>Cornwall</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <!--e-->
                <div id="e" class="counties-container">
                    <h2>East</h2>
                    <p class="select"><a class="selectall" title="Select All">Select All</a> | <a class="deselectall" title="Deselect All">Deselect All</a></p>
                    <fieldset class="e-t">
                        <input type="checkbox" /><label>Essex</label>
                    </fieldset>

                </div>

                <!--s-->
                <div id="s" class="counties-container">
                    <h2>South</h2>
                    <p class="select"><a class="selectall" title="Select All">Select All</a> | <a class="deselectall" title="Deselect All">Deselect All</a></p>
                    <fieldset class="s-t">

                        <input type="checkbox" /><label>Hampshire</label>

                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <!--se-->
                <div id="se" class="counties-container">
                    <h2>South East</h2>
                    <p class="select"><a class="selectall" title="Select All">Select All</a> | <a class="deselectall" title="Deselect All">Deselect All</a></p>
                    <fieldset class="se-t">
                        <input type="checkbox" /><label>London</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <!--scot-->
                <div id="scot" class="counties-container">
                    <h2>Scotland</h2>
                    <p class="select"><a class="selectall" title="Select All">Select All</a> | <a class="deselectall" title="Deselect All">Deselect All</a></p>
                    <fieldset class="scot-t">

                        <input type="checkbox" /><label>Edinburgh</label>

                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <!--ni-->
                <div id="ni" class="counties-container">
                    <h2>Northern Ireland</h2>
                    <p class="select"><a class="selectall" title="Select All">Select All</a> | <a class="deselectall" title="Deselect All">Deselect All</a></p>
                    <fieldset class="ni-t">
                        <input type="checkbox" /><label>Belfast</label>
                    </fieldset>  

                </div>

                <!--w-->
                <div id="w" class="counties-container">
                    <h2>West</h2>
                    <p class="select"><a class="selectall" title="Select All">Select All</a> | <a class="deselectall" title="Deselect All">Deselect All</a></p>
                    <fieldset class="w-t">

                        <input type="checkbox" /><label>Wrexham</label>

                    </fieldset>
                </div>

            </div> <!--.counties-->

        </div> <!--.areas-->

<div class="clear"></div>

</div> <!--#map-box-->


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the JavaScript I have in the page:

```
<script>
    function showValues() {
      var fields = $(":input").serializeArray();
      $("#results").empty();
      jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field){
        $("#results").append(field.value + " ");
      });
    }

    $(":checkbox, :radio").click(showValues);
    $("select").change(showValues);
    showValues();

    $('#form').submit(function() {
    if ($('input:checkbox', this).is(':checked') &&
        $('input:radio', this).is(':checked')) {
        // everything's fine...
    } else {
        alert('Please select something!');
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: First thing I see, you have this: `$('#form')`: this implies there's an element with id `form` and there is no such element. To target all your forms, just use `$('form')`. That's a start. I encourage you to check out http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials -- also, welcome to StackOverflow!